# XSLT Template and Overriding

Tags: xslt

I've got a system where I want a base file and several possible "template" snippit type files. Below is an example:

```
<BookClub ref="WashingtonClub101">
    <ReadingList ref="SummerReadingList">
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID1</Id>
            <Name>Favorite Book</Name>
            <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
            <Cost>$12.00</Cost>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID2</Id>
            <Name>Boring Book</Name>
            <Author>Fun Author</Author>
            <Cost>$30.00</Cost>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID4</Id>
            <Name>Summer Book 7</Name>
        </Book>
        <Remove Id="GUID5" />
    </ReadingList>
</BookClub>

<ReadingList Id="SummerReadingList">
    <Book>
        <Id>GUID3</Id>
        <Name>Summer Book 1</Name>
        <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
        <Cost>$40.00</Cost>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Id>GUID4</Id>
        <Name>Summer Book 2</Name>
        <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
        <Cost>$40.00</Cost>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Id>GUID5</Id>
        <Name>Summer Book 3</Name>
        <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
        <Cost>$40.00</Cost>
    </Book>
</ReadlingList>

<BookClub Id="WashingtonClub101">
    <ReadingList>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID101</Id>
            <Name>Washington Club Book</Name>
            <Author>Mr. Book</Author>
            <Cost>$18.00</Cost>
        </Book>
    </ReadingList>
    <Location>
        <Name>Seattle Public Library</Name>
    </Location>
</BookClub>
```

The first BookClub is the base and if references (via ref) the snippits. The expected output is below, although I don't care about order at all.

```
<BookClub>
    <ReadingList>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID1</Id>
            <Name>Favorite Book</Name>
            <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
            <Cost>$12.00</Cost>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID2</Id>
            <Name>Boring Book</Name>
            <Author>Fun Author</Author>
            <Cost>$30.00</Cost>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID3</Id>
            <Name>Summer Book 1</Name>
            <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
            <Cost>$40.00</Cost>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID4</Id>
            <Name>Summer Book 7</Name>
            <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
            <Cost>$40.00</Cost>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID101</Id>
            <Name>Washington Club Book</Name>
            <Author>Mr. Book</Author>
            <Cost>$18.00</Cost>
        </Book>
    </ReadingList>
    <Location>
        <Name>Seattle Public Library</Name>
    </Location>
</BookClub>
```

Basically, I want the base to merge with the snippits, with the base being the override on collision. Ideally, I don't have to specify each of the nodes that merge (my real problem space has a lot more tags). Id in the real system are all GUIDs (real ones GUID1 and such were used for readability reasons) and can be assumed to be unique and used as keys.

I have an XSLT that can merge the files, but I can't figure out how to override properties etc.

Here is my current XSLT, it basically is just a merge. But it just smashes the 2 files together.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name ="filename"></xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/BookClub">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document($filename)/BookClub/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're asking.  Is the supplied code your input, or desired output?  Why not post your code so far?  And as far as template overrides, there are many examples and references both here and elsewhere, since it is essentially the foundation of XSLT.  Can you identify what's particular about your requirement?

Comment: Which version of XSLT? -- "*I have an XSLT that can merge the files*" Why don't you post it (or a minimized version of it), so that we have something to work with.

Comment: The top is the input (in 3 different files) and the bottom is the expected output (in one file). I didn't post what I had for 2 reasons. 1, my XSLT isn't doing what I want it to right now at all, and 2, because merging of 2 XSLT files is trivial.

Comment: **Which version of XSLT?** -- "*I have an XSLT that can merge the files*" Why don't you post it (or a minimized version of it), **so that we have something to work with**.

Comment: It's very important to tell us whether this is XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. In XSLT 2.0 a solution using for-each-group is quite easy; in 1.0 it will probably be much more convoluted.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. I'm using .NET 4.5 so both are supported.

Comment: "*I'm using .NET 4.5 so both are supported.*" Is that so? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: No, only XSLT 1.0 is supported. If merging two files is easy, then why would you withhold your current XSLT stylesheet from us?

Comment: I'm very new to XSLT. I thought I had read somewhere that .NET 4.5 added support for XSLT 2.0. Apparently I misread. I've edited my post to add my current XSLT that just merges 2 XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I am still puzzled by many things in your question, but in the interest of moving this forward, let us consider two files:

**BookClub.xml (this is the file which is the input XML file for the XSL transformation):**

```
<BookClub ref="WashingtonClub101">
    <ReadingList ref="SummerReadingList">
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID1</Id>
            <Name>Favorite Book</Name>
            <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
            <Cost>$12.00</Cost>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID2</Id>
            <Name>Boring Book</Name>
            <Author>Fun Author</Author>
            <Cost>$30.00</Cost>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Id>GUID4</Id>
            <Name>Summer Book 7</Name>
        </Book>
        <Remove Id="GUID5" />
    </ReadingList>
</BookClub>
```

**file2.xml (this is an external file whose path will be passed to the stylesheet as parameter):**

```
<ReadingList Id="SummerReadingList">
    <Book>
        <Id>GUID3</Id>
        <Name>Summer Book 1</Name>
        <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
        <Cost>$40.00</Cost>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Id>GUID4</Id>
        <Name>Summer Book 2</Name>
        <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
        <Cost>$40.00</Cost>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Id>GUID5</Id>
        <Name>Summer Book 3</Name>
        <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
        <Cost>$40.00</Cost>
    </Book>
</ReadingList>
```

Now, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="filepath2" select="'file2.xml'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ReadingList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document($filepath2)/ReadingList/Book[not(Id=current()/Book/Id or Id=current()/Remove/@Id)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Remove"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied as stated above, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookClub ref="WashingtonClub101">
   <ReadingList ref="SummerReadingList">
      <Book>
         <Id>GUID1</Id>
         <Name>Favorite Book</Name>
         <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
         <Cost>$12.00</Cost>
      </Book>
      <Book>
         <Id>GUID2</Id>
         <Name>Boring Book</Name>
         <Author>Fun Author</Author>
         <Cost>$30.00</Cost>
      </Book>
      <Book>
         <Id>GUID4</Id>
         <Name>Summer Book 7</Name>
      </Book>
      <Book>
         <Id>GUID3</Id>
         <Name>Summer Book 1</Name>
         <Author>Favorite Author</Author>
         <Cost>$40.00</Cost>
      </Book>
   </ReadingList>
</BookClub>
```

In order to incorporate the additional file (or files), we need to understand how you intend to pass the file paths to the transformation process: each path as an individual parameter, or a string containing many paths or ...?

I also see that the files do not have exactly the same structure. If that's your real situation, you won't be able to process them using the same code.

Finally, it's not clear if there can be collisions between the external files themselves - and if yes, how these need to be handled.